# Simulator not "talking" in code lab: Build Actions for the Google Assistant (Level 1)

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

If I follow the instructions for this [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/) up until "Debug your Action" at the bottom of step 4, I get the bizarre behavior pictured below.  Does anyone know why? Note that the display shows a question, but the audio never plays (look on left to see it's absence).  I have reproduced this twice now, once yesterday and again today (re-creating the entire project from scratch following the code lab instructions, each time). This appears to be a bug in the "phone" surface only.  Switching to Speaker or Smart Display resolves the problem.

[image]

Here is the content of the Response tab:

```
    {
  "conversationToken": "[]",
  "finalResponse": {
    "richResponse": {
      "items": [
        {
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "Welcome! What is your favorite color?"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "44a0a46f-b4e3-4985-a7ea-59bb90ef3bb9"
    }
  }
}
```

And the Debug tab:

```
    {
  "response": "Alright. Getting the test version of my test app.",
  "expectUserResponse": false,
  "conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
  "audioResponse": "//NExAARiC...",
  "debugInfo": {
    "assistantToAgentDebug": {
      "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=c37cbcc968134768a12a05cdbfb8459c' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjRlZjUxMThiMDgwMGJkNjBhNDE5NDE4NmRjYjUzOGZjNjZlNWViMzQifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJhY3Rpb25zLWNvZGVsYWIzLWRlOWNkIiwiZXhwIjoxNTMwMjE0OTk5LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJqdGkiOiJmODgwZjZiMmQxZDQyYjMxODc4Nzg2YjY4MjI3Y2U3MzhhYTE5MGFlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTMwMjE0ODc5LCJuYmYiOjE1MzAyMTQ1Nzl9.A6oNz2UWwaBN8ARTAFNRXr-hWYEVChQVI-iUCCVX0xLFZTRm8Ns5b5XvC-_aLg4yLJmf2LuSJj1hKua1QLjzzMt_ifHNqwOTASk_3fUumCdItNivqljPahUdonEOq5uUPORIuvzzLb11kD67sEnSadHydv1vCE4MNLxCRDLQvYDoWwd3TIk2TkRpnbbjve4uOPpp7q9_8NPwek4AypNj73peSzB0bTKaSKlCUTtUf4EGKO5siGpDeOgxo4W4L98FXkwvQGfzyPv_KF24S4dzkn0bpnVSqTemA8nmEGNrmnDYyikmfQ1LZnq9vpWwtBkIcNFMCNdz94CAta9Eotk8Kw'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHFP1TkMd6vXAW26cxs7CBqCuZCoFXlPyocAtISGTpGDkJ1gPSlh1ALbe64yGW7Qs_X6IPoKrS952cuMhKrJisLTSA\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-06-28T19:35:56Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1530214879800\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"Talk to my test app\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}'",
      "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"ABwppHFP1TkMd6vXAW26cxs7CBqCuZCoFXlPyocAtISGTpGDkJ1gPSlh1ALbe64yGW7Qs_X6IPoKrS952cuMhKrJisLTSA\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-06-28T19:35:56Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1530214879800\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"KEYBOARD\",\"query\":\"Talk to my test app\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"}]}],\"requestType\":\"SIMULATOR\"}"
    },
    "agentToAssistantDebug": {
      "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"conversationToken\":\"[]\",\"finalResponse\":{\"richResponse\":{\"items\":[{\"simpleResponse\":{\"textToSpeech\":\"Welcome! What is your favorite color?\"}}]}},\"responseMetadata\":{\"status\":{\"message\":\"Success (200)\"},\"queryMatchInfo\":{\"queryMatched\":true,\"intent\":\"44a0a46f-b4e3-4985-a7ea-59bb90ef3bb9\"}}}"
    },
    "sharedDebugInfoList": []
  },
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Welcome! What is your favorite color?"
        }
      }
    ],
    "suggestionsList": [],
    "agentLogoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/voice/opa/partner_icons/generic_3p_avatar.png",
    "agentStyle": {
      "primaryColor": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "borderRadius": 0,
      "backgroundColor": "",
      "backgroundImageUrl": ""
    }
  },
  "clientError": 0,
  "is3pResponse": 1
}
```

Finally here is my intent, which you can see has the id (in url bar) that shows it is the intent that is matched.

[image]

I can't figure out why this might be happening.  Thanks for any input.

Comment: Are you using the same Google account for both Dialogflow and Actions Console?

Comment: If you are launching with the simulator, maybe you should add the event Google Assistant Welcome too, so that it knows with what intent to start

Comment: Yes, same account, I am following the code lab instructions to go from Dialogflow straight to simulator, which I believe guarantees this, but to be sure I have just now manually verified that the account shown in the simulator and Dialogflow are the same.

Comment: Remi - As mentioned in my question I can see the correct intent is being started.  You can also see this on the right side of my first screenshot in the DISPLAY tab as the correct response is shown.  What is odd is that the text is not being spoken as you can see on left.  It is still happening today (3 days in a row).

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

There seems to be an inconsistency when using simulator with the phone surface using the simulator experience today vs. the screenshot at the codelab which was taken in beginning of May (you can see the date there).

Switching to a different surface will make the simulator pronounce the response to you. However, as you probably noticed, the "display" section of a simulator has correct response. Having developed actions in the past, I don't think you have a problem as far learning how to develop good actions.

Old answer:

Please unselect "Set this intent as end of conversation" toggle for your "Default Welcome Intent". It is located under "Responses" section of the intent's UI in Dialogflow console.

In general, you would want to have this toggle on only for intents that will end the conversation with your action.

Comment: Does not work, tried previously and again just now.  The result is the same as in my screenshots, except you have to say or enter "cancel" to end the interaction.  Further if you look at the code lab link I shared you can see that they leave that checkbox checked, just as in my screenshot and provide no instruction to uncheck it.  I'd be tempted to think this is just an in progress kind of bug, where the next page/module will resolve it, but it specifically asks you to test at this point with different results than happen in their simulator screenshot.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I misinterpreted your question. I thought the issue was that your action left the conversation. 

Hm, I can actually reproduce your error. This is interesting. However, as you probably noticed, the "display" section of a simulator has correct response. Having developed actions in the past, I don't think you have a problem. Notice that the screen shot in the code lab was taken back in May, so the way simulator responds now may have changed (I am not sure though).

Note, the app will "talk" if you switch surface to something other than the phone in simulator.

Comment: Yep.  I updated the question about it only being the phone surface, based on your comment.  I will file a bug in the code lab issue tracker.  If you change your answer to the code lab is wrong / simulator is broken for phone and you can resolve it by switching to a different surface I will accept that.  Thank you for verifying the issue.