# Actions on Google - configure Simulator to display my test app

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

My test app is displayed only on the 'display' tab and not on the conversation menu on the left.

[Expected](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/index.html#3):
[image: Google's Example]

Actual:

[image: My attempt]

How can it be fixed?

Comment: You will get only speech responses on left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short term fix, until the bug in the simulator is resolved, is to change your surface.  You can switch to speaker if you want to hear the response.  Note that you can only swap surfaces when you are not in an active conversation, if you are in one, just click cancel, and then switch surfaces.  If you do switch to speaker you will not see the display anymore, but it will say the question you are seeking.  Please don't be discouraged, this was not a bug in your code, it is in the simulator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mark Scheel for the info

Comment: Seems that this bug is still there.

Answer (score 0):

it is only the first TTS (i.e Welcome! ... )  that you may not hear back the audio file. It is a bug and they are working to fix it. But as long as you see "Welcome!..." in the display card now, your action is working

Comment: How do you know they are working on it?  That's great to hear, as I asked the same question earlier here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090316/simulator-not-talking-in-code-lab-build-actions-for-the-google-assistant-lev