# Actions Google Simulator not working

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

5I'm creating a google actions for Google Home, i'm using dialogflow and firebase functions and database to create the all thing.
So far everything was working good together but yesterday an error occured that i dont understand.

When i want to test my agent on the Simulator section of Google Actions, the agent is not responding even if in the logs i can see that the response is actually received by the simulator as shown here

[image]

And it answer this in the simulator

[image]

The response is empty and i have this simple error in the Debug section

[image]

It worked perfectly before but i may have change one thing that crashed everything and i can't find it.

**EDIT**

As recommended by @Prisoner, i've checked the History to find this

[image]

So i checked the logs and i got this (after Dialogflow Request and Dialogflow fulfillment request who were looking good)

It seems that the Dialogflow fulfillement response is having problem with URL ???

[image]

**EDIT2**

My URL fulfillment (firebase functions) was wrong, now that i have changed it, the log in my History seems ok :

[image]

But i'm always getting the same error on the Simulator.

Comment: Please include your code/error as text instead of an image.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the "response" and "debug" tabs from the simulator?

Comment: That does seem very odd. Make sure logging to stackdriver is turned on in dialogflow (from the settings screen) and see if it is giving any indication what it is getting from your webhook and what it is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs show that your fulfillment is not deployed correctly and the URL is pointing to a HTML 404 page. This will cause your app to stop responding.

Answer (score -1):

You may be running into the recent "first TTS is not spoken" bug in the simulator.  I suggest changing your surface to speaker instead of phone.  [You can read more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133773/actions-on-google-configure-simulator-to-display-my-test-app/51159673#51159673).

Comment: The thing is, as i have shown in the first screen, my code is actually working because the simulator receive a proper response "Welcome to ... agent, what can i do for you ?". This is why its weird.

Comment: In that case my solution will probably work, have you tried it?  Switch the surface to speaker

Comment: Ok.  I see you added more information.  It appears your fulfillment URL is not correct, best I can tell your interaction matches an intent (the debug tab JSON would help verify this) and you have custom fulfillment turned on but the URL is wrong or moved. Is that possible?

Comment: It's getting weirder and weirder, the URL of my fulfillment was indeed wrong, but now that i have changed it, in the History of Dialogfow i dont have any error but in the simulator i still don't have a response !

Comment: Which surface are you using?  Still on speaker?

Comment: Yup still on speaker, but now i have errors in logs of Google Actions. I really don't understand what's going on here.

Comment: Can you post the updated logs after you fix the fulfillment URL if you are still running into this issue?